# hoverable dropdown menu not showing

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a hoverable dropdown menu that will work like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar).

However, it seems that my website's dropdown menu does not appear.

After inspecting the code (using Developer Tools in Chrome), I found out that my dropdown menu is covered up by my *#content* div.

What should I do to bring the dropdown menu to the top?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url("../background/home.jpg")
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#home {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(236, 130, 53, 0.75);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  float: right;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#content {
  margin-top: 61px;
  animation: fadein 5s;
}

.menu a {
  color: #0000ff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.menu:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="navigation-menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="menu">
        <a href="#">Transport</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `overflow: hidden;` from the `<ul>`

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(236, 130, 53, 0.75);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This was stopping the content from flowing outside of the div to give you the effect you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow: hidden` from `ul`. It is causing your `.dropdown-content` to be hidden.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url("../background/home.jpg")
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#home {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(236, 130, 53, 0.75);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  float: right;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#content {
  margin-top: 61px;
  animation: fadein 5s;
}

.menu a {
  color: #0000ff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.menu:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="navigation-menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="menu">
        <a href="#">Transport</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
  </div>
</body>
```